# using Linq to break flat table results into object collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database return result which has flatten results like below. I want to use Linq to break the flat results into primary classes with the items populating the primary class items property collection.

```
public class Result
{
 public string PrimaryKey { get; set; }
 public string Status { get; set; }
 public string ItemName { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectA
{
 public string PrimaryKey { get; set; }
 public string Status { get; set; }

 public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
}

public class Item
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
 GetObjectAs();
}

static List<ObjectA> GetObjectAs()
{
 // this is our table results
 List<Result> results = new List<Result>();
 results.Add(new Result()
 {
  PrimaryKey = "1",
  Status = "Done",
  ItemName = "item1"
 });
 results.Add(new Result()
 {
  PrimaryKey = "2",
  Status = "Fail",
  ItemName = null
 });
 results.Add(new Result()
 {
  PrimaryKey = "3",
  Status = "Done",
  ItemName = "item2"
 });
 results.Add(new Result()
 {
  PrimaryKey = "3",
  Status = "Done",
  ItemName = "item3"
 });

 List<ObjectA> returnResults = new List<ObjectA>();

 // need to break into 3 ObjectA objects

 // ObjectA 1 needs an Item added to its Items collection with ItemName item1

 // ObjectA 2 has no items since the ItemName above is null

 // ObjectA 3 needs 2 Items added to its Items collection item2 and item3

 // return our collection
 return returnResults;
}
```

PS this is just sample code, I know you shouldn't expose a List as a public property and should return an IEnumerator instead of the actual List etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` to group the results by the primary key, then you can operate on the subset of rows within the group to obtain the status (hopefully all values for `Status` are the same, which is why I used `First`) and the list of items.

```
var items = results.GroupBy(r => r.PrimaryKey).Select(grp => new ObjectA() 
            {
                PrimaryKey = grp.Key,
                Status = grp.Select(r => r.Status).First(),
                Items = grp.Where(r => r.ItemName != null)
                       .Select(r => new Item() { Name = r.ItemName }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return results
    .GroupBy(r => r.PrimaryKey)
    .Select(grp => new ObjectA
    {
        PrimaryKey = grp.Key,
        Status = grp.First().Status,
        Items = grp.Where(i => i.ItemName != null).Select(i => new Item { Name = i.ItemName }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: This returns 4 objects, not 3.

Comment: @Kenoyer130 - It returns 3 objects for me.